# Sum Column Value

Tags: mysql, sql

I Have query result like this , Select Type,Jan,FEB From TableName :

```
    +-----------+------+------+
    | Type      | JAN  | FEB  |
    +-----------+------+------+
    | MATIC     |  137 |  128 |
    | MOPED     |   41 |   23 |
    | MOPED PRM |    8 |    9 |
    | SPORT     |   55 |   62 |
    +-----------+------+------+
    4 rows in set (1.23 sec)
```

I want to add up the columns jan and columns feb, be like this

```
    +-----------+------+------+------+
    | Type      | JAN  | FEB  | TOT  |
    +-----------+------+------+------+
    | MATIC     |  137 |  128 | 165  |
    | MOPED     |   41 |   23 |  64  |
    | MOPED PRM |    8 |    9 |  17  |
    | SPORT     |   55 |   62 | 117  | 
    +-----------+------+------+------+
    4 rows in set (1.23 sec)
```

is there a command such as

```
select type, jan, feb, sum (jan) + sum (feb) As TOT
From Table Name
```

This is my syntax

```
Select SubTbl2.jenis,
sum(If(Month = 1 and Year = 2013 ,Result,0)) as 'JAN',
sum(If(Month = 2 and Year = 2013,Result,0)) as 'FEB'
From (
select SubTbl1.jenis,month(SubTbl1.TglAmb) as Month,
year(SubTbl1.tglAmb) as Year,
count(SubTbl1.jenis) as Result
From (
select jual_leasing.TglAmb,jual_leasing.NoMsn,typemotor.jenis
,lokasi.lokasi3s
from jual_leasing
left join typeconvert
on jual_leasing.typeK = typeconvert.typesystem
left join typemotor
on typeconvert.typeconv = typemotor.type
left join lokasi
on jual_leasing.kodelok = lokasi.kodelokasi
where 
lokasi.lokasi3S = 'YMS PURWODADI 3S'
group by jual_leasing.NoMsn)
as SubTbl1
group by SubTbl1.jenis,Month,Year )
as SubTbl2 group by SubTbl2.jenis;
```

The result is on Top , i try to add script on line 4 , with 
    JAN + FEB as TOT

but there is stil warning :
   ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'JAN' in 'field list'

Tq For advanced

Comment: In SQL, single quotes indicate a string. Table names and field names should be using backticks `SELECT [...] as \`JAN\`` (or don't use any at all...).

Comment: Tq Marty , turns out the problem is the basic logic, I'm confused with the length of myscript ,: D tq ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the beginning of your query with this :

```
Select SubTbl2.jenis,
sum(If(Month = 1 and Year = 2013 ,Result,0)) as 'JAN',
sum(If(Month = 2 and Year = 2013,Result,0)) as 'FEB',
sum(If(Month = 1 and Year = 2013 ,Result,0)) +
sum(If(Month = 2 and Year = 2013,Result,0)) as 'TOT'
From (
```

Or

```
Select SubTbl2.jenis,
sum(If(Month = 1 and Year = 2013 ,Result,0)) as 'JAN',
sum(If(Month = 2 and Year = 2013,Result,0)) as 'FEB',
sum(If((Month = 1 or Month = 2) and Year = 2013,Result,0)) as 'TOT'
From (
```

Comment: The second answer is more simple alternative , Tq .. :)

Answer (score 4):

To obtain tour desired output, simply do:

```
select type, jan, feb, jan + feb As TOT 
from TableName
```

You do not need `SUM`, that is designed to add the values of different rows.

**edit** For your actual query, yes you can add two sums. Also, the following should work for you:

```
sum(If((Month = 1 or Month = 2) and Year = 2013 ,Result,0)) as 'TOT',
```

Comment: Tq Trogdor , but there's warning ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'JAN' in 'field list'  , tq for the answer

Comment: @ony seven Have you used this exact query or a different one?. If you used a different query update your question. My query should work if your first one does

Comment: @Troqdor , i just update my question , there is 3 related tables , i just update my question , tq..

Answer (score 1):

The MySQL documentation on [arithmetic functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/arithmetic-functions.html) indicates that `+` is indeed the addition operator.

So, your query would be:

```
select type, jan, feb, jan + feb from table
```

Sum works over columns and not rows; you'd use this if you wanted the sum of both columns added together.

P.S. 137 + 128 = 265

Comment: Tq for the answer Ben

Answer (score 1):

I think you will find this question is getting down-voted because it is not really about programming - this is more of a general SQL syntax question. That being said, I think you should just be able to sum your values:

```
select type, jan, feb, jan + feb As TOT From Table Name
```

Comment: Tq Roberto , :) but there's warning on syntax
ERROR 1054 (42S22): Unknown column 'JAN' in 'field list'

Comment: Maybe there is something wrong with the example you gave? SQL is usually case-sensitive, so make sure the query has the same capitalization as the actual column name.

Comment: Ready, I'll check it , Tq

Comment: i have two sub table on my syntax